# I am trying to use a function that uses FormatWith() and I get an error in C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying to build an email template. I got what is suppose to be  working example but I am having problems trying to get FormatWith() to resolve in one of the functions.

```
private static string PrepareMailBodyWith(string templateName, params string[] pairs)
{
    string body = GetMailBodyOfTemplate(templateName);

    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.Length; i += 2)
    {
        // wonder if I can bypass Format with and just use String.Format
        body = body.Replace("<%={0}%>".FormatWith(pairs[i]), pairs[i + 1]);
        //body = body.Replace("<%={0}%>",String.Format(pairs[i]), pairs[i + 1]);
    }
    return body;
}
```

Comment: I have included all these NameSpaces trying to resolve it.
`using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.String;
using System.IFormatProvider;
using System.Object;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was easier to use the .Replace() then to jump through all the other hoops.  Thank you for your suggestions.

```
        string email = emailTemplate
        .Replace("##USERNAME##", userName)
        .Replace("##MYNAME##", myName);
```

This seems to be the simplest solution to my email template issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) to me.

You need to reference the namespace the extension method lives in at the top of your file.

Example:

```
namespace MyApp.ExtensionMethods
{
    public class MyExtensions
    {    
        public static string FormatWith(this string target, params object[] args) 
        { 
            return string.Format(Constants.CurrentCulture, target, args); 
        }    
    }
}
```

...

```
using MyApp.ExtensionMethods;

...

private static string PrepareMailBodyWith(string templateName, params string[] pairs)
{
    string body = GetMailBodyOfTemplate(templateName);

    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.Length; i += 2)
    {
        // wonder if I can bypass Format with and just use String.Format
        body = body.Replace("<%={0}%>".FormatWith(pairs[i]), pairs[i + 1]);
        //body = body.Replace("<%={0}%>",String.Format(pairs[i]), pairs[i + 1]);
    }
    return body;
}
```

Comment: I am already using this one `    public static string FormatWith(this string target, params object[] args)
    {
        return string.Format(Constants.CurrentCulture, target, args);

    }'  I got the code from [link](http://www.waytocoding.com/2011/02/how-to-send-email-with-prepared.html)

Comment: That extension method lives in a namespace then.  You simply need to add a `using` statement referencing that namespace at the top of the file.

Comment: Tried, says NameSpace Can not be found I added the link that I go the example from.  [example code](http://www.waytocoding.com/2011/02/how-to-send-email-with-prepared.html)

Comment: In that example, the extension method is defined next to where it is used.  I would recommend you add it to its own file and class, and name it something like "StringExtensions", provide it a namespace, and reference that namespace where it is consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.Format()` instead, like you suggested...

```
body = body.Replace(String.Format("<%={0}%>", pairs[i]), String.Format("<%={0}%>", pairs[i+1]);
```

This assumes you want both the search string and the replacement string to be formatted.